# Appropriate clustering method for 1 or 2 dimensional data

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have a set of data I have generated that consists of extracted mass (well, m/z but that not so important) values and a time.  I extract the data from the file, however, it is possible to get repeat measurements and this results in a large amount of redundancy within the dataset.  I am looking for a method to cluster these in order to group those that are related based on either similarity in mass alone, or similarity in mass and time.

An example of data that should be group together is:

m/z        time

337.65     1524.6

337.65     1524.6

337.65     1604.3

However, I have no way to determine how many clusters I will have.  Does anyone know of an efficient way to accomplish this, possibly using a simple distance metric?  I am not familiar with clustering algorithms sadly.

Comment: There are many clustering techniques, and the right one to use will depend on the nature of the data. If you could show a scatterplot of the data, it would help a lot for determining which approach to use.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

Read the section about hierarchical clustering and also look into DBSCAN if you really don't want to specify how many clusters in advance.  You will need to define a distance metric and in that step is where you would determine which of the features or combination of features you will be clustering on.

Comment: Out of the typical "cluster analysis" methods, DBSCAN is at least a saner choice than k-means. But I believe the proper approach is to not use cluster analysis at all, but just grouping successive records if they don't change enough.

Comment: Hackartist, you mentioned that the epsilon (distance) metric needs to be specified here, however I am not clear exactly on you mean one should pick it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set a threshold?

If successive values (by time) do not differ by at least `+-0.1` (by m/s) they a grouped together. Alternatively, use a relative threshold: differ by less than `+- .1%`. Set these thresholds according to your domain knowledge.

That sounds like the straightforward way of preprocessing this data to me.

Using a "clustering" algorithm here seems total overkill to me. Clustering algorithms will try to discover much more complex structures than what you are trying to find here. The result will likely be surprising and hard to control. The straightforward change-threshold approach (which I would *not* call clustering!) is very simple to explain, understand and control.

Comment: I think you may be right.  I thought there might be a fairly simple algorithm I could use as I am concerned about efficiency but initially I think I will try something such as this, or use some reasonable metric in order to include the time and mass when grouping them.

Comment: This is as simple and efficient as it gets. When your data is sorted by time, it requires a single linear scan over the data set and memory to compare two records; no algorithm can get faster than this.
So definitely give it a try. In fact, this may even be a sensible preprocessing before trying any other more complex algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple one dimension K-means clustering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Standard_algorithm)  is appropriate and can be used directly. The only issue is selecting appropriate K. The best way to select a good K is to either plot K vs residual variance and select the K that "dramatically" reduces variance. Another strategy is to use some information criteria (eg. Bayesian Information Criteria).

You can extend K-Means to multi-dimensional data easily. But you should be beware of scaling the individual dimensions. Eg. Among items (1KG, 1KM) (2KG, 2KM) the nearest point to (1.7KG, 1.4KM) is (2KG, 2KM) with these scales. But once you start expression second item in meters, probably the alternative is true.

Comment: k-means is not appropriate here.  k means is only useful when you know ahead of time how many clusters there are, but he's stated that he doesn't know how many there will be.

Comment: @RunningWild: To know how many cluster there is you can use a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: @RunningWild I do have suggestions on how to choose a proper K in my answer.

Comment: k-means is total overkill and inappropriate here. Just because it was called "clusters" in the question does not make it k-means style clusters...